# Regex match number, a multiple of 5, between 1 to 1000 inclusive

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I've been facing this problem that I cannot solve.

```
compiler = re.compile(r'\d*[05]')
result = compiler.findall('0 20 201 95 5 52 35 999 40 19 50 1000 245 1050 118 2500')
```

Desired output:
`['20', '95', '5', '35', '40', '50', '1000', '245']`

The closest that I can achieve, based on my code above:
`['0', '20', '20', '95', '5', '5', '35', '40', '50', '1000', '245', '1050', '2500']`

I am supposed to provide my answer in only the dashed portion of the code `re.compile(r'--------')`.

If someone can help me out that'll be great, thanks.

Comment: Is it a requirement that it needs to be done with regexps? Not really the right tool for the job.

Comment: unfortunately the requirement of the question is to use only regex..

Answer (score 4):

The requirement can be met by using the [regex pattern](https://regex101.com/r/IKPb6A/1), `\b(?!0)(?:\d{0,2}[05]\b|1000)\b`.

**Demo:**

```
import re

compiler = re.compile(r'\b(?!0)(?:\d{0,2}[05]\b|1000)\b')
result = compiler.findall('0 20 201 95 5 52 35 999 40 19 50 1000 245 1050 118 2500')
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['20', '95', '5', '35', '40', '50', '1000', '245']
```

**Explanation of the regex:**

- `\b` : Word boundary
- `(?!0)` : Negative lookahead asserting that there should not be `0` ahead of the current position.
- `(?:` : Start of non-capturing group

  - `\d{0,2}` : A digit, zero to two times
  - `[05]` : 0 or 5
  - `\b` : Word boundary
  - `|1000` : OR 1000
- `)` : End of non-capturing group
- `\b` : Word boundary

Updated as per the following valuable suggestion by [The fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5424988/the-fourth-bird)
:

> To prevent a partial match for 1000, you can start with the word
> boundary, assert for not zero and wrap the whole alternation in the
> non capture group, ending with a word boundary again
> `\b(?!0)(?:\d{0,2}[05]\b|1000)\b`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use regex for this. You can use a comprehension:

```
result = [i for i in data.split() if not (n := int(i)) % 5 and n <= 1000 and n]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
result = []
for i in data.split():
    n = int(i)
    if not n % 5 and n <= 1000 and n:
        result.append(i)
```

Comment: unfortunately the requirement of the question is to use regex, but appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @depperm

```
\b(?!\b0\b)(\d{0,2}[05]|1000)\b
```

would be the perfect regex for your demand.

My idea just works for a single number

```
^\d{0,2}[05]$|^1000$
```

Explanation:

- `^` shows, that the string has to start here
- `/d{0,2}` stands for 0,1 or 2 numbers
- `[05]` the number 0 or 5 because the all multiples of 5 end with 0 or 5
- `$` end of the string
- `|` stands for the operator or
- `^1000$` stands for the string 1000

but as already pointed out you could look in too other ways as well

Comment: I believe `\b(?!\b0\b)(\d{0,2}[05]|1000)\b` is needed to get all the results

Comment: @depperm do you have any number not found by my expression? i thought i have them all covert

Comment: with the input provided (all the numbers in a single string) I believe you need something like `\b` not `^..$`

Comment: see [code](https://replit.com/@depperm/UnsightlyClumsyFilename#main.py)

Comment: Yes you are right i missed the usecase a bit your expression is superior

Comment: If you use `\b(?!\b0\b)` it can also match `000` As non of the matches should start with a zero, you can use `\b(?!0)`

Answer (score 1):

When it's all in one string, we need to add boundaries to our search. Another answer was close, but we can't match by `^` and `$` when the single string contains multiple values.

`\b` or word boundaries makes sure that there aren't additional digits before or after a matching string.

Pattern: `\b0\b|(\b\d{0,2}[05]\b|\b1000\b)`

All the desired matches are in group 1

https://regex101.com/r/Efhcsb/2

Comment: shouldn't capture 0

Comment: should NOT capture 0

Comment: Yes, by putting everything in group 1 we can exclude `\b0\b` from our solution set.

Comment: in python it returns `['', '20', '95', '5', '35', '40', '50', '1000', '245']`

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a standard number range generator between 5 and 1000 to get
`[5-9]|[1-9]\d|[1-9]\d{2}|1000`

Then replace the last digit with '[05]' to get `5|[1-9][05]|[1-9]\d[05]|1000`.

Refactor that and add word boundary's '\b' to get `\b(?:5|[1-9]\d?[05]|1000)\b`

Python test:

```
>>> import re
>>> Rx = re.compile(r'\b(?:5|[1-9]\d?[05]|1000)\b')
>>> Rx.findall('0 20 201 95 5 52 35 999 40 19 50 1000 245 1050 118 2500')
['20', '95', '5', '35', '40', '50', '1000', '245']
```